# How to filter undesired output in uart connection with screen

Tags: uart, gnu-screen, tty

I'm connecting to an IP Camera's uart pins with the command :

`sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`

and I got a root shell but it keeps flooding the console so I can't interact clearly with it ...

do you have an idea how to make it stop flooding and just respond what i ask ?

Comment: What `flooding` means? Excessive logging? Garbage?

Comment: yes it's logging things I don't care about... I'll try to kill the process logging if there is no other way.

Comment: If there is `linux` running it might be possible that `dmesg` is continuously printing some logs - try `dmesg -n1`.

Comment: dmesg is not found, this looks like linux with only busybox

Comment: `dmesg` is available in `busybox` - try `busybox dmesg`.  It's also possible that these are not kernel logs. Can you access the device remotely, for example with ssh or telnet?

Comment: I thought i saw busybox but its not here i must be wrong. here is the only commands available : https://pastebin.com/n7pCeSCR I cant find the process to kill to stop the flood...

Comment: and no i cant ssh or telnet on the device... but there is "telnetd".. i dont know if i can run a telnet server to connect it remotely ?

Comment: Try `telnetd -l /bin/sh` to start telnet daemon and then connect with telnet from another machine.

Comment: Or try to disable serial logs: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180295/discussion-between-neolex-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).